# Can't uninstall Debugger for Chrome extension from Visual Studio Code? Perpetual uninstall

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am VERY NEW to learning JavaScript, and I was looking for a simple way to test my basic JavaScript, without using the chrome developer tools inside my Chrome Browser.  I thought it might be faster than hoping back and fourth to a browser and typing things in the browser's console.

I thought the extension "Debugger for Chrome" would aid in this, but I don't think it's what I want, or I can't figure out how to use it(very new to this)?

I am trying to uninstall it, and I just get a perpetual 'Uninstalling' icon, but it never actually uninstalls(pic attached below).  It's been like that for a half hour in the background.  I've tried restarting vscode and my PC, and I can't seem to get it out of my editor.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9uZXv.png

Answer (score 0):

I even tried to delete vsCode completely, including the registry items I could get at, after reinstall I had the same error.  Restarts of PC also didn't help.  But for some reason, this morning after starting up my PC, I was able to remove the extension.

So my issue is resolved, not onto figuring out easier ways to debug with vsCode.